# What is the best way to add login and logout code in Meteor Cucumber Steps?

Tags: meteor

I have the following code in Meteor cucumber test implementation. This is mainly using WedDriver.io to perform browser based login and logout. I am wondering if I can call, Meteor.userId() in a Given step definition?

```
this.Given(/^I am logged out$/, function (callback) {
  console.log("Given: I am logged out ");
  //always signout before sigingin in
  helper.world.browser.
    url(helper.world.cucumber.mirror.rootUrl).
    waitForExist('#at-nav-button').
    waitForVisible('#at-nav-button').
    click('#at-nav-button').
    pause(200);

  callback();
});

this.Given(/^I am logged in$/, function (callback) {
  console.log("Given: I am logged in ");

  //always signout before sigingin in
  helper.world.browser.
  url(helper.world.cucumber.mirror.rootUrl).
  waitForExist('#at-nav-button').
  waitForVisible('#at-nav-button').
  click('#at-nav-button').
  pause(100);


  // make sure the user is Authenticated
  helper.world.browser.
  url(helper.world.cucumber.mirror.rootUrl+"sign-in").
  waitForExist('.at-pwd-form').
  waitForVisible('.at-pwd-form').
  setValue('#at-field-email', 's@y.com').
  setValue('#at-field-password', 's123').
  click('#at-btn').
  pause(100);

  callback();
});
```